# rails assets precompile css order

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, zurb-foundation

I'm using zurb with rails. I overrode some of zurbs default css by adding changes to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
But precompilation seems to append all the other css files to this one. Is there any way to ensure that a certain css rule will be the last one to be precompiled to application.css?

Answer (score 1):

the order in which the assets are compiled can be specified in the manifest files for js and css http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Answer (score 0):

Use many requires in your `application.css.scss`

```
*= require css1
*= require css2
...
```